# Exclusion Script

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm trying to create an exclusion script that will not send to people who do not have at least 16 matches in a related DE. I feel like i'm really close but haven't been able to get it to work yet.

This is what I have so far:

```
%%[ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Shane_RA", "family_ID", _subscriberkey)) > 15]%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It assumes it's a AMPScript block.  All you need is this without the block syntax:

```
ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Shane_RA", "family_ID", _subscriberkey)) > 15
```

Comment: That did it! I also have the operator wrong, was suppose to be <. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is it possible to put more than  2 condition something like this:

(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE1", "Environment", Environment)) < 1)

(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE2", "Partner", Partner)) < 1)
?

Comment: Yes.  The whole thing just needs to evaluate to `true` or `false`.  In your example it'd be this:  `ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE1", "Environment", Environment)) < 1 and ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("DE2", "Partner", Partner)) < 1`

Answer (score 1):

Remember, your DE `Shane_RA` should be using template as DomainExclusion (Shown in below screenshot)

`ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Shane_RA", "family_ID", _subscriberkey)) < 15`

[image]

Comment: Why would it need to use a DE template?

Comment: Creating the DE this way would allow for your exclusions to work properly.

Comment: That's not how I understand those to work.  Do you have some documentation to support it?

Comment: Once I tried with with normal DE and did not work, after consulting Support team, they guided me to follow this process.