# Exclude Domains From Exact Target

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way we can exclude some domains from exact target , such that whenever we send the email to campaign members , the members with one of the domain provided are not sent any email automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there's no way to manage that as some sort of centralized setting but you can work with a Data Extension holding the domain names and an Exclusion Script to filter based on that. Exclusion Scripts are available when setting up "User Initiated Sends".

The Exclusion Script would lookup the Data Extension with the domains to check if the Email field contains a value that matches the data extension records.

Here's an example how Exclusion scripts work: [Exclusion Script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111394/exclusion-script)

When you use Journey Builder or Triggered sends you directly select "Domain Exclusion Data Extensions" without any scripts. Not sure why that doesn't work with user initiated emails, yet.

Comment: Domain Exclusions do work with UI Sends now.  You have to create the DE with a DomainExclusion Template. Once one is created, the option will show in the Audience section of your Send Definition.

Comment: @adamspriggs In the Domain Exclusion DE is is just the domain without the @? So google.com vs @google.com? Is this documented anywhere on how it works? I found this: http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/canvas_activities/configuring_the_send_email_activity/configure_the_send_email_activity/ But it doesn't even reference the DomainExclusion template.