# Exclusion List in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, dataextensions, exclusion-script

I've set up a journey in Journey Builder however I want to exclude a list of customers. When sending an email from Content Builder it allows me to exclude and suppress lists but this option is not there on Journey Builder.

Has anyone else experienced this issue and is there a way around it? Our data is not in real time so require the manual imported list to exclude for this journey.

Thanks
Keith

Answer (score 2):

Content Builder and UI sends allow you to exclude `Data Extensions` . With Journey Builder, you are only allowed to to suppress / exclude customer via Suppression Lists, Domain Exclusion DEs or Exclusion Scripts. In addition to this, if you add customers to an Auto suppression list then they are excluded from all sends automatically.

[image]

**References:**

- [Exclusion Script](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/111394/exclusion-script)
- [Exclude Domains From Exact Target](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/131415/exclude-domains-from-exact-target)
- [AutoSuppression List](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=mc_es_auto_suppresion_lists.htm)

Comment: Within the Exclusion Script is there a way to exclude lists? Would anyone know what code to use?

Comment: If you are using an exclusion script then you would have to evaluate it against a data extension. If you need to use list then suppression lists would be the way to go